# Could not initialize proxy with graphql-spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I am using: graphql-spring-boot and graphql-java-tools for the implementation.

**movie.graphqls**

```
type Movie {
    id: Short
    name: String
    poster: String
    releaseDate: String
    runtime: String
    storyline: String
    rated: String
    rating: String
    inserted: String
}


type Query {
    movies: [Movie]
    movie(id: ID!): Movie
}
```

**Movie model**

```
@Entity
public class Movie {
    private Short id;
    private String name;
    private String poster;
    private Date releaseDate;
    private Time runtime;
    private String storyline;
    private String rated;
    private double rating;
    private Timestamp inserted;
}
```

As you can see i have no relationship with other models.
finally the class which implement **GraphQLQueryResolver**

```
@Component
public class Query implements GraphQLQueryResolver {
    @Autowired
    private MovieRepository movieRepository;
    public List<Movie> movies() {
        return this.movieRepository.findAll();
    }
    public Movie movie(Short id) {
        return this.movieRepository.getOne(id);
    }
}
```

the following query works fine:

```
{
  movies{
    name
    rating
  }
}
```

but this query:

```
{
  movie(id: 1){
    name
  }
}
```

gives me the following error:

> Exception while fetching data (/movie/rated) : could not initialize proxy [com.example.demo.model.Movie#1] - no Session

Comment: not the same question. the problem in that question is the relationship between models, here i have no relationship !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing `getOne` to `findOne`

```
public Movie movie(Short id) {
    return this.movieRepository.findOne(id);
}
```

I think using `getOne` requires the call to be within a transaction context. Hence the error - no session.

Comment: Had the same issue, I've spent 2 hours trying to solve not the actual problem that I had and you saved me, thanks! Would never guess that getById is different than findById.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the naming of strategy in your conguration file **application.properties**

```
hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
```

Comment: Cannot resolve configuration property 'hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy'.